# coding structure in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a question from newbie in both Java and Netbeans.  I have searched a lot in google before posting it here.

I am using netbeans to create a gui application.  In the standard books, the structure for java coding is suggested as,

```
class className{
  field names

  constructor(){

  }

  method1(){

  }

  method2(){

  }


  main method(){

  }
}
```

In Netbeans,

```
class ClassName{

   constructor(){
        initComponents();
   }

   initComponents(){

   }

   //autogenerated code for methods related to swing actions

    action1(){

    }

    action2(){

    }        

   main method(){

   }

  field Names;

}
```

My question is, where do i write method1() and method2()?  Should i have to put the fieldnames at the end or on top? - the autogenerated fieldnames cannot be edited.  So, should i have to write the field names which i declare on top or at the bottom.  I know that anywhere will work.  But i want to make sure i am coding them at the right place.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some if this is personal preference.  Some people like the fields at the end of the class, I personal like them at the start.

I tend to put the constructor first, followed by the methods and allow the auto generated code to sit towards the bottom and I put inner classes at the end.

But that's just me.

Comment: +1 for suggestion.  So, the field names which we declare are on top and the field names which are generated are at the bottom.  After the consutructor() all user defined methods(), the main method will be just above the autogenerated field names.  Is that Ok?

Comment: The basic recommendation is to try and remain consistent as possible, but yeah, your suggestions should be fine

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how Netbeans works, but if it generates code in your file, perhaps you should store your own functions somewhere else, this way you can freely choose your structure without having Netbeans taking up a section of your file.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can write your methods wherever you think the best place is.

For Swing app, Netbeans will use this rather awkward class structure you've just showed - with the instances variables, constants and the like at the bottom of the class.

Personally I prefer to put the constants at the top, followed by variables, constructors, public, protected, default and private methods (in this order) - then any inner class (if there is any).

There must be a way to change Netbeans class template - but I've never digged into the templates setup of Netbeans for the classes structure - only for the header's comment.